# UIImagePickerController(didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo) NOT Called in UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8.2

I have a UITableViewCell button to take an image and place it back in the cell. When I call the UIImagePickerController and pick/take the image, it should call the following function

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject], sender:AnyObject)
```

For some reason it doesn't call this function, therefore, I cannot place the chosen UIImage to the current cell. Any help would be much appriciated.

This is the button code

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose image souruce", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take Image", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is the imagePickerController function on didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

The self.reloadData is the function that runs the UITableView and reload the data.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject], sender:AnyObject) {
    var btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    //Gets the chosen cell indexPath
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(btnPos)!
    let currentCell:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TableViewCell
    let iamgePicked:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    currentCell.cellImageOulet.image = iamgePicked
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.loadData()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentCell:TableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TableViewCell
```

This will not work. Table View have some kind of declarative style of data source.
This means you need save images that you want to show in table view, and use they in tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath